# Annual Flux Data Tiff shows strange stripes

Tags: google-solar-api

The annual Flux data for geolocation 50.243767211631294, 8.865066826274766 (Germany) has a strange stripe in it. See image[annual Flux Tiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71OF3.png)
The retrieved Quality is MEDIUM

Did anyone had this issue already?

It is a error in the input data. I cant do anything